# How can I split the resizable panel vertically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, panel

How can I split the resizable panel vertically using current code HTML,CSS and JavaScript. Right now this code is working for horizontal resizable split. What are the changes I would have to do in this current code.

How can I split the resizable panel vertically using current code HTML,CSS and JavaScript. Right now this code is working for horizontal resizable split. What are the changes I would have to do in this current code.

```js
// A function is used for dragging and moving
function dragElement(element, direction) {
  var md; // remember mouse down info
  const first = document.getElementById("first");
  const second = document.getElementById("second");

  element.onmousedown = onMouseDown;

  function onMouseDown(e) {
    //console.log("mouse down: " + e.clientX);
    md = {
      e,
      offsetLeft: element.offsetLeft,
      offsetTop: element.offsetTop,
      firstWidth: first.offsetWidth,
      secondWidth: second.offsetWidth
    };

    document.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
    document.onmouseup = () => {
      //console.log("mouse up");
      document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
    }
  }

  function onMouseMove(e) {
    //console.log("mouse move: " + e.clientX);
    var delta = {
      x: e.clientX - md.e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY - md.e.clientY
    };

    if (direction === "H") // Horizontal
    {
      // Prevent negative-sized elements
      delta.x = Math.min(Math.max(delta.x, -md.firstWidth),
        md.secondWidth);

      element.style.left = md.offsetLeft + delta.x + "px";
      first.style.width = (md.firstWidth + delta.x) + "px";
      second.style.width = (md.secondWidth - delta.x) + "px";
    }
  }
}


dragElement(document.getElementById("separator"), "H");
```

```css
.splitter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

#separator {
  cursor: col-resize;
  background-color: #aaa;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='30'><path d='M2 0 v30 M5 0 v30 M8 0 v30' fill='none' stroke='black'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  /* Prevent the browser's built-in drag from interfering */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#first {
  background-color: #dde;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 10px;
}

#second {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="splitter">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="separator"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. You will need another `SVG` image to design properly the separator because the previous one was created for horizontal purpose.

```js
// A function is used for dragging and moving
function dragElement(element, direction) {
  var md; // remember mouse down info
  const first = document.getElementById("first");
  const second = document.getElementById("second");

  element.onmousedown = onMouseDown;

  function onMouseDown(e) {
    //console.log("mouse down: " + e.clientX);
    md = {
      e,
      offsetLeft: element.offsetLeft,
      offsetTop: element.offsetTop,
      firstHeight: first.offsetHeight,
      secondHeight: second.offsetHeight
    };

    document.onmousemove = onMouseMove;
    document.onmouseup = () => {
      //console.log("mouse up");
      document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
    }
  }

  function onMouseMove(e) {
    //console.log("mouse move: " + e.clientX);
    var delta = {
      x: e.clientX - md.e.clientX,
      y: e.clientY - md.e.clientY
    };

    if (direction === "V") // Vertical
    {        
      // Prevent negative-sized elements
      delta.x = Math.min(Math.max(delta.y, -md.firstHeight),
        md.secondHeight);

      element.style.top = md.offsetTop + delta.x + "px";
      first.style.height = (md.firstHeight + delta.x) + "px";
      second.style.height = (md.secondHeight - delta.x) + "px";
    }
  }
}


dragElement(document.getElementById("separator"), "V");
```

```css
.splitter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;  
}

#separator {
  cursor: col-resize;
  background-color: #aaa;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='3'><path d='M2 30 0 M5 0 v30 M8 0 v30' fill='none' stroke='black'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  /* Prevent the browser's built-in drag from interfering */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#first {
  background-color: #dde;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 10px;
}

#second {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="splitter">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="separator"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I forgot to mention, I want to keep the horizontal split as it is.
I want both horizontal as well as vertical split. 
You can skip the image.

Comment: I did answer to your question as you presented it. I consider you have all the elements required for you to do it yourself from this step forward.